# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: java, oracle11g

I've got a weird problem in Oracle query running from Java with Oracle 11g. The same query worked good with Oracle 10g. tool_availability is a view.

```
final String SELECT_SQL = "select * " +
            "from tool_availability " +
            "where tool_code = ? " +
            "and tool_number = ? " +
            "and unit = ? " +
            "and part_id = ? ";

ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL);
ps.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);
ps.setFetchSize(1);
ps.setString(1, tool_code);
ps.setString(2, tool_number);
ps.setString(3, unit);
ps.setString(4, part_id);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

The query has space before and after '?' mark. The same query is not working with 11g and I'm getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

If I remove the space before and after '?' mark. The same query is working with 11g.

Could anybody give some insight what could be the problem?

Comment: My guess is it is the difference in JDBC.  Are you importing the ORACLE JDBC driver or the generic one?  Are you importing a different driver based upon Oracle version?  I would look there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to avoid to set String in preparedstatement.

In preparedStatement , you need to set actual type.

```
ps.setString(1, tool_code);
ps.setInt(2, tool_number);
ps.setInt(3, unit);
ps.setString(4, part_id);
```

like that you have to do

Comment: Thanks for your response. The datatype for all columns are VARCHAR2.